# Django - recreate database from migration files | Sync production and development databases

Tags: mysql, django, database, migration, production

My situation is the following:

I have a Django project in a production environment which uses a mysql database.
Also, I have a copy of the same Django project in a local environment which uses a mysql database too. What I want to do is set the following workflow to deploy database changes into production:

1. Make changes in local models.
2. Run makemigrations.
3. Run migrate.
4. Add, commit and upload the migration file to production.
5. Run simply "migrate" in production environment to update the
   production database.

Actually, for some past reason both databases aren't completetly synced and for do this workflow, I need both databases works with same migration files and keep synced.

**Any help on how to do that? How can i create this local database fully synced with production?**

I tried the following things:

- Create an empty local database and simply apply the "migrate" command.
- Export the production database schema and create a local database based on it.

None of the above worked because when i try to run locally the django server, first he says that i have 100 migrations unaplied and, when i do the migrate says...

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InvalidBasesError: Cannot resolve bases for []
>   This can happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g. contrib.auth)
>    in an app with no migrations; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#dependencies for more

Thank you so much.